# "google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message" is reported when I try to save a checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am training a model with tf and the process of training is going well. but when it comes to the step of saving checkpoints, the error occured as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer.py", line 110, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "trainer.py", line 100, in train
    self.model.saver.save(sess, model_save_path, global_step=current_step)
  File "/search/odin/zhangshusen/Python-3.6.8-tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1203, in save
    save_debug_info=save_debug_info)
  File "/search/odin/zhangshusen/Python-3.6.8-tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/saver.py", line 1246, in export_meta_graph
    graph_def=ops.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(add_shapes=True),
  File "/search/odin/zhangshusen/Python-3.6.8-tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3238, in as_graph_def
    result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)
  File "/search/odin/zhangshusen/Python-3.6.8-tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3166, in _as_graph_def
    graph.ParseFromString(compat.as_bytes(data))
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

there is a point that the embedding parmas of the model is loaded from a txt file, which is the pre-trained embeddings with another model. code is as below:

```
    def create_pretrained_emb_from_txt(self, vocab, embed_file, name = None, dtype=tf.float32):
        vocab_size = len(vocab)
        print("start load {} vocab: {}".format(embed_file, vocab_size))
        embs_dict, emb_size = utils.load_emb(embed_file)
        print("load {} end {}".format(embed_file, len(embs_dict)))
        embs = np.random.rand(vocab_size, emb_size).astype(np.float32)
        for v in vocab:
            if v in embs_dict:
                embs[vocab[v]] = np.array(embs_dict[v], dtype=np.float32)
        emb_mat = tf.get_variable(name=name,
         initializer=tf.convert_to_tensor(embs, dtype=dtype), trainable=True)
        print("init tensor done")
        return emb_mat
```

when i call this function to init embeddings, the error occured. Instead, when i init emebedings randomly with code below, the error nerver hapend and the training goes well

```
domain_init_scope = math.sqrt(6.0 / (domain_vocab_size + emb_dim))
domain_emb_shape = [domain_vocab_size, emb_dim]
domain_embedding_table = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(domain_emb_shape, -domain_init_scope, domain_init_scope))
```

Comment: tf.train.Saver is used to save checkpoints, which is initialized as self.saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables()) , and was used as self.model.saver.save(sess, model_save_path, global_step=current_step)

Comment: Which `TensorFlow` version are you using?